# Windows Form - Change Array Elements from Textbox Input C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Create a change password program that allows users to change their password by entering their email and security pin, but code works fine but it doesn't seem to make changes to the textfile array when I input a new password into the password textbox.

```
string filename = "./userinfo.csv";
using (var path = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
{
    string line = reader.ReadLine(); 
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] fields = line.Split(',');
        if (fields[1] == email && fields[3] == txtPin.Text)
        {
            fields[2] = txtNewPassword.Text;
            MessageBox.Show("Password Changed");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter an valid Username or Pin");
        }
    }
}
```

When I enter input into the textbox it would go to the textfile and change that specific array.

Comment: Changing the third element of the array doesn't change the file from which you have read the line and then split it to build the array. You need to rebuild the line and then rewrite the file. Look at [File.ReadAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=net-7.0) and [File.WriteAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines?view=net-7.0) methods

Comment: hi @Steve i tried reading it i still couldnt get anything out of it as im new to programming